# Unable to show multiple location on google map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity

I'm trying to pass my address via `intent.putExtra()` from other activity to `MapActivity`  and inside the `MapActivity` i have done the Geocode. It has no error but when I run, it doesn't show the location. Can anyone tell me what am I missing or do wrong?

FYI: I have already pass the address from Listview Activity to DisplayItem activity (It works). Now i want to pass it to MapActivity

Bellow is my other activity (`ListViewActivity`)

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ShoppingMall.this, Displayitem.class);
            if (adapter.getItem(position).length > 0) {

                intent.putExtra(Displayitem.EXTRA_ADDRESS, adapter.getItem(position)[4]);
                intent.putExtra(MapsActivity.EXTRA_ADDRESS, adapter.getItem(position)[4]);

            }

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I want to put

```
intent.putExtra(MapsActivity.EXTRA_ADDRESS, adapter.getItem(position)[4]);
```

into this

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.myMap) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ShoppingMall.this,MapsActivity.class);
        //Intent.putExtra

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is my `MapActivity`

```
public static final String EXTRA_ADDRESS ="address";
private Bundle extras;
List<Address> location;
double lati, lon ;
.
.
.
.


private void getAddress(GoogleMap googleMap)  {

   try {
       mMap = googleMap;

       Intent intent = getIntent();
       extras = intent.getExtras();
       Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
       String address = extras.getString(this.EXTRA_ADDRESS);
       location = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
       if (location.size() > 0) {
           lati =location.get(0).getLatitude();
           lon =location.get(0).getLongitude();
           MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                   .title("")
                   .position (new LatLng(lati, lon));
           mMap.addMarker(options);
       }

   }catch (Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();

   }
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    getAddress(googleMap);
    setUpMap();

}
```

ps: Newbie in android

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ShoppingMall.this, Mapactivity.class);
            if (adapter.getItem(position).length > 0) {

                intent.putExtra(Displayitem.EXTRA_ADDRESS, adapter.getItem(position)[4]);
                intent.putExtra(MapsActivity.EXTRA_ADDRESS, adapter.getItem(position)[4]);

            }

            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It does show on Map.  Can I make the seperate class ? Like 
Intent intent = new Intent(ShoppingMall.this, Mapactivity.class);
and
Intent intent = new Intent(ShoppingMall.this, Displayitem.class);

Comment: Yes above you write MapActivity code  and intent pass displayitem. So you can create both seperate class.

Comment: Hye, i realize the problem  and I have update my Question. hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

```
private void addMarkersToMap() {
    mMap.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < private void addMarkersToMap() {
mMap.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < location.size(); i++) {         
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(location.get(i).getPos().getLat(), location.get(i).getPos().getLon());
        BitmapDescriptor bitmapMarker;
        switch (location.get(i).getState()) {
        case 0:
            bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED);
            Log.i(TAG, "RED");
            break;
        case 1:
            bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN);
            Log.i(TAG, "GREEN");
            break;
        case 2:
            bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE);
            Log.i(TAG, "ORANGE");
            break;
        default:
            bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED);
            Log.i(TAG, "DEFAULT");
            break;
        }               
        mMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ll).title(location.get(i).getName())
                .snippet(getStateString(location.get(i).getState())).icon(bitmapMarker)));

        Log.i(TAG,"Car number "+i+"  was added " +mMarkers.get(mMarkers.size()-1).getId());
    }
}
```